# multi replace in postgresql query using perl

Tags: regex, postgresql, perl

I'm cleaning some text directly in my query, and rather than using nested replace functions, I found this bit of code that uses perl to perform multiple replacements at once: [multi-replace with perl](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2020/01/27/strings-multi-replace-plperl.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.multi_replace(string text, orig text[], repl text[]) 
RETURNS text 
AS $BODY$ 
  my ($string, $orig, $repl) = @_;
  my %subs;

  if (@$orig != @$repl) {
     elog(ERROR, "array sizes mismatch");
  } 
  if (ref @$orig[0] eq 'ARRAY' || ref @$repl[0] eq 'ARRAY') {
     elog(ERROR, "array dimensions mismatch");
  } 

  @subs{@$orig} = @$repl;
  
  my $re = join "|",
     sort { (length($b) <=> length($a)) } keys %subs;
  $re = qr/($re)/;

  $string =~ s/$re/$subs{$1}/g;

  return $string;
$BODY$ language plperl strict immutable;
```

Example query:

```
select

name as original_name, 
multi_replace(name, '{-,&,LLC$}', '{_,and,business}') as cleaned_name

from some_table
```

The function finds the pattern LLC at the end of the name string but removes it instead of replacing it with "business."

How can I make this work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

When the strings in `@$orig` are to be matched literally, I'd actually use this:

```perl
my ($string, $orig, $repl) = @_;

# Argument checks here.

my %subs; @subs{ @$orig } = @$repl;

my $pat =
   join "|",
      map quotemeta,
         sort { length($b) <=> length($a) }
            @$orig;

return $string =~ s/$re/$subs{$&}/gr;
```

In particular, `map quotemeta,` was missing.

(By the way, the `sort` line isn't needed if you ensure that `xy` comes before `x` in `@$orig` when you want to replace both `x(?!y)` and `xy`.)

---

But you want the strings in `@$orig` to be treated as regex patterns. For that, you can use the following:

```perl
# IMPORTANT! Only provide strings from trusted sources in
# `@$orig` as it allows execution of arbitrary Perl code.

my ($string, $orig, $repl) = @_;

# Argument checks here.

my $re =
   join "|",
      map "(?:$orig->[$_])(?{ $_ })",
         0..$#$orig;

{
   use re qw( eval );
   $re = qr/$re/;
}

return $string =~ s/$re/$repl->[$^R]/gr;
```

---

However, in your environment, I have doubts about the availability of `use re qw( eval );` and `(?{ })`, so the above may be an unviable solution for you.

```perl
my ($string, $orig, $repl) = @_;

# Argument checks here.

my $re =
   join "|",
      map "(?<_$_>$orig->[$_])",
         0..$#$orig;

$re = qr/$re/;

return
   $string =~ s{$re}{
      my ( $n ) =
         map substr( $_, 1 ),
            grep { $-{$_} && defined( $-{$_}[0] ) }
               grep { /^_\d+\z/aa }
                  keys( %- );

      $repl->[$n]
   }egr;
```

Comment: Added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While the regexp tests for `LLC$` with the special meaning of the `$`, what gets captured into `$1` is just the string `LLC` and so it doesn't find the look-up value to replace.

If the only thing you care about is `$`, then you could fix it by changing the map-building lines to:

```
 @subs{map {my $t=$_; $t=~s/\$$//; $t} @$orig} = @$repl;

 my $re = join "|",
    sort { (length($b) <=> length($a)) } @$orig;
```

But it will be very hard to make it work more generally for every possible feature of regex.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this `plperl` function in the linked blog post is to find/replace strings, not regular expressions. `LLC` being found with `LLC$` as a search term does not happen in the original code, as the search terms go through `quotemeta` before being included into `$re` (as also sugggested in [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191292/238814))

The effect of removing the `quotemeta` transformation is that `LLC` at the end of a string is matched, but since as a key it's not found in `$subs` (because the key there is`LLC$`), then it's getting replaced by an empty string.

So how to make this work with regular expressions in the `orig` parameter?

The solution proposed by @ikegami does not seem usable from `plperl`, as it complains with this error: *Unable to load re.pm into plperl*.

I thought of an alternative implementation without the `(?{ code })` feature: each match from the main alternation regexp can be rechecked against each regexp in `orig`, in a code block run with `/ge`. On the first match, the corresponding string in `repl` is selected as the replacement.
Code:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION pg_temp.multi_replace(string text, orig text[], repl text[]) 
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  my ($string, $orig, $repl) = @_;
  my %subs;

  if (@$orig != @$repl) {
     elog(ERROR, "array sizes mismatch");
  } 
  if (ref @$orig[0] eq 'ARRAY' || ref @$repl[0] eq 'ARRAY') {
     elog(ERROR, "array dimensions mismatch");
  } 

  @subs{@$orig} = @$repl;
  
  my $re = join "|", keys %subs;
  $re = qr/($re)/;

  # on each match, recheck the match individually against each regexp
  # to find the corresponding replacement string
  $string =~ s/$re/{ my $r; foreach (@$orig) { if ($1 =~ $_) {$r=$subs{$_}; last;} } $r;}/ge;

  return $string;
$BODY$ language plperl strict immutable;
```

Test

```
=> select pg_temp.multi_replace(
    'bar foo - bar & LLC',
    '{^bar,-,&,LLC$}',
    '{baz,_,and,business}'
   );

       multi_replace        
----------------------------
 baz foo _ bar and business
```

Comment: You should precompile the patterns in `@$orig`: `@$orig = map qr/$_/, @$orig;`. Still, this could perform quite poorly for long lists. I've added my answer to add a solution that doesn't suffer from this problem in a sec.